# Why is SimpleDateFormat changing the date?

Tags: java, date, formatting, simpledateformat

Given the following code:

```
[...]

    public void testFormatDateString() throws ParseException {

        String dateString = new java.util.Date().toString();

        System.out.println(dateString);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date date = format.parse(dateString);

        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }

[...]
```

Before:
`Sat Aug 19 18:26:11 BST 2017`

After:
`Sat Jan 07 17:26:11 GMT 2017`

Why is the date changed?

Comment: You don't even write to `dateString` second time. Are you sure you did not miss one more `dateString = date.toString();`?

Comment: I have corrected the example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The upper case `Y` is for ["week year"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), which has 364 or 371 days instead of the usual 365 or 366. With lower case `y` (which is used by `Date#toString`) everything works as expected:

```
public void testFormatDateString() throws ParseException {

    String dateString = new java.util.Date().toString();

    System.out.println(dateString);

    // Force to Locale.US as this is hardcoded in Date#toString
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);

    Date date = format.parse(dateString);

    System.out.println(date.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
Sat Aug 19 17:50:39 GMT 2017
Sat Aug 19 17:50:39 GMT 2017
```

[See on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/2fJvCw)

As mentioned in the comments, make sure to include `Locale.US` when parsing the `dateString`, as that is hardcoded in `Date#toString`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774834/what-pattern-should-be-used-to-parse-the-date-string-returned-by-the-tostring-of) for details.

Comment: Somehow I got a `ParseException` from OP's code. Any idea why?

Comment: The upper case `Y` is only supported with JDK 7+. Were you using an older version?

Comment: Actually, your code throws an exception as well. I'm using JDK 8. I am in a different locale. Do you think that matters? `Locale.getDefault()` returns ja_JP.

Comment: Interesting. What does your `dateString` look like?

Comment: `Sat Aug 19 18:56:28 BST 2017` Do you think I should post a question asking about this behaviour?

Comment: I'm also getting an exception in my local Eclipse. This seems worth a question IMHO. If it wouldn't work on ideone... I'm guessing it has to do with the locale, as `toString` hardcodes `Locale.US`. Edit: Yes, works when I force the default locale to `Locale.US`.

Comment: I update the example to pass in the default Locale. Do you still get the exception?

Comment: @Sweeper Locale matters, because month and day of week are in English (Sat Aug). You should use `Locale.ENGLISH` (or `Locale.UK`, or `Locale.US`) instead of default

Answer (score 1):

The first of all I would say that I completely agree with Marvins [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45774617/5728095) but I hope someone will be interested in more technical details.

Following [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `SimpleDateFormat` you can't find example with `YYYY`. But it works and validation is passed. Checking deeper:

```
public class SimpleDateFormat extends DateFormat {
//....
/**
 * Returns the compiled form of the given pattern. The syntax of
 * the compiled pattern is:
 * <blockquote>
 * CompiledPattern:
 *     EntryList
 * EntryList:
 *     Entry
 *     EntryList Entry
 * Entry:
 *     TagField
 *     TagField data
 * TagField:
 *     Tag Length
 *     TaggedData
 * Tag:
 *     pattern_char_index
 *     TAG_QUOTE_CHARS
 * Length:
 *     short_length
 *     long_length
 * TaggedData:
 *     TAG_QUOTE_ASCII_CHAR ascii_char
 *
 * </blockquote>
 * ....
 *
 * @exception NullPointerException if the given pattern is null
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the given pattern is invalid
 */
    private char[] compile(String pattern) {
        ...
        if ((tag = DateFormatSymbols.patternChars.indexOf(c)) == -1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal pattern character " +
                                               "'" + c + "'");
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Checking allowed pattern symbols (that used in validation condition) `DateFormatSymbols.patternChars`:

```
public class DateFormatSymbols implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    ...
    static final String  patternChars = "GyMdkHmsSEDFwWahKzZYuXL";
    ...
}
```

`Y` is valid pattern element, what's it means (lets check constants in same `DateFormatSymbols` class)?

```
static final int PATTERN_ERA                  =  0; // G
static final int PATTERN_YEAR                 =  1; // y
static final int PATTERN_MONTH                =  2; // M
static final int PATTERN_DAY_OF_MONTH         =  3; // d
static final int PATTERN_HOUR_OF_DAY1         =  4; // k
static final int PATTERN_HOUR_OF_DAY0         =  5; // H
static final int PATTERN_MINUTE               =  6; // m
static final int PATTERN_SECOND               =  7; // s
static final int PATTERN_MILLISECOND          =  8; // S
static final int PATTERN_DAY_OF_WEEK          =  9; // E
static final int PATTERN_DAY_OF_YEAR          = 10; // D
static final int PATTERN_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH = 11; // F
static final int PATTERN_WEEK_OF_YEAR         = 12; // w
static final int PATTERN_WEEK_OF_MONTH        = 13; // W
static final int PATTERN_AM_PM                = 14; // a
static final int PATTERN_HOUR1                = 15; // h
static final int PATTERN_HOUR0                = 16; // K
static final int PATTERN_ZONE_NAME            = 17; // z
static final int PATTERN_ZONE_VALUE           = 18; // Z
static final int PATTERN_WEEK_YEAR            = 19; // Y
static final int PATTERN_ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK      = 20; // u
static final int PATTERN_ISO_ZONE             = 21; // X
static final int PATTERN_MONTH_STANDALONE     = 22; // L
```

and here you can find the `Y` pattern element (the name is readable clear):

```
static final int PATTERN_WEEK_YEAR            = 19; // Y
```

`*_WEEK_YEAR` provides some confuse if we expecting single `YEAR` (following naming convention `PATTERN_YEAR`). Also we can find

```
static final int PATTERN_YEAR                 =  1; // y
```

Difference of meaning we can search in internet (in wiki for example). But what is the difference of using it in code? Continuing the check of using constants in `SimpleDateFormat` we can detect that `PATTERN_WEEK_YEAR` and `PATTERN_YEAR` are used in similar way for almost all cases. But with small logical difference (just find elements using in `DateFormatSymbols.java`)... and as result we'll be sure that code provides same to wiki terming meaning.

---

...following this java investigation way (using java doc and sources) we can clarify almost all questions without additional help with getting deep `JDK` knowledges.

Comment: There _is_ actually an explanation and an example for `Y` in the javadoc you linked.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually the same date, British Summer Time (BST) is exactly one hour ahead of GMT.

Note also that 'Y' is the Week of the year, What you want to use is 'y'

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Except that month and day also was changed. So it's not the same date.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Comment: And don't confuse "Week of the year" with "week year".